# Finding the likelihood ratio hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

A single scaled cauchy has density:

$$f_{X\mid θ}(s)=\frac{2}{τ}⋅\frac{\theta}{\theta^2+s^2}$$

Find the likelihood ratio for testing $H_0:θ=1.4$ versus $H_1:θ=2.3$

Suppose that we reject $H_0$ when $f{(X\mid θ_0)}/f(X\mid θ_1)≤1.3$ Solve this inequality for $X$.

---

I assume that I plug in the given $\theta$ for each model, but what do I plug in for $s^2$?

Comment: Why not write the density as $f(x\mid \theta)$ instead? More importantly, you need to be  aware of the support of the distribution. Without mentioning the domain of $x$, density is meaningless. And what is the $\tau$ doing here?

Comment: It's a Cauchy distribution

Comment: No it isn't....

Comment: I'm given that $[X|θ]$ is a single scaled cauchy with the above density

Comment: The above is no density, hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$f_{X\,\mid\,\theta}(s)$ is the value at $s$ of the density function of the distribution of the random variable $X.$

$f(X\mid\theta)$ is that **same** function evaluated at $X,$ so $f(X\mid \theta)$ is itself a random variable.

Since it's the same function, you need to put $X$ where $s$ is in the first line in your question.

Comment: but we still aren't given an X value?

Comment: @Anna : In any actual use of this hypothesis test, you would observe a value of $X.$

Comment: So for the likelihood ratio, do we just omit the $s^2$